# vba Macro - Using ForumulaR1C1 to get data from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use vba to automate a simple process by getting a data from another sheet in the same workbook. I'm cannot just copy because the data is updated dynamically, if there is changes to the other sheet, it will be affected.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Sheet2'!R[7]C[4]"
```

This is my first time doing vba and I think the R[7]C[4] meant sort of the coordinates of getting the value either vertically or horizontally based on the positivity and negativity of the numbers.

Sheet1

```
2-Jul
-------
item1     item2     3
item1.1   item2.2   43
          total     46
3-Jul
-------
item1     item2     3
item1.1   item2.2   41
          total     44
```

Sheet2

```
1-Jul     
2-Jul     46 (works here)
3-Jul     44 (does not work here)
```

It will run through the dates on sheet 2 and show the total accordingly on the 2nd column. This is what I did.

```
For Each cell In Range("A1:A3")
    If cell.Value = selDate Then
        Range("B" & cell.row).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Sheet1'!R[3]C[3]"
    End If
Next cell
```

I place my selected cell on `2-Jul` and it got the cell correct and took `46` but as for the second one that I ran by placing my selected cell on `3-Jul`, it took data just one cell down from `46` than actually getting `44`.

Comment: have you looked at the value of `ActiveCell.Formula`? this shows it in the A1 style

Comment: Hey @SeanC, thanks for the comment and I just tried that. It seemed like the ActiveCell in "='Sheet1'!C" & ActiveCell.row + 3 isn't getting the cell that I am selecting in Sheet1. I'm guessing I did not understand fully on the ActiveCell part. Why does the ActiveCell always on the first row.

Comment: with the `For Each`, you will need to refer to **cell**, instead of ActiveCell

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb as I suspect that your use of offset R1C1 formulas was due to some problems coming up with an adequate formula for retrieving the 'Total' from Sheet1 for each date on Sheet2.

```
Sub get_dated_total()
    Dim rw As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, sFormulaR1C1 As String

    sFormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX(INDEX(Sheet1!C3,MATCH(RC1,Sheet1!C1,0)):INDEX(Sheet1!C3,ROWS(C3)),MATCH(""total"",INDEX(Sheet1!C,MATCH(RC1,Sheet1!C1,0)):INDEX(Sheet1!C,ROWS(C)), 0)), """")"
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For rw = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If IsDate(.Cells(rw, 1)) Then
                If CBool(Application.CountIf(ws1.Columns(1), .Cells(rw, 1).Value)) Then
                    .Cells(rw, 2).FormulaR1C1 = sFormulaR1C1
                End If
            End If
        Next rw
    End With

    Set ws1 = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image: R1C1 for floating total]

Answer (score -1):

Well, might not be the best solution but I guess the latter ActiveCell.row refers to Sheet2 if I'm on Sheet2 Selection. Now I have to store a temp row number instead at the start to get the true ActiveCell.row which is the row of `2-Jul`

```
Dim tmpRow As Integer
tmpRow = ActiveCell.Row
```

Then I'm gonna call it later

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "='Sheet1'!C" & tmpRow + 3
```